# Community Issue after latest salesforce release

Tags: visualforce, community, release-notes, spring-20

**Has anybody faced below issue after Spring 20 release on their SB:**

Consider a Community has a VF page which has many links (made up of a href tags), when an internal user tries to login and access the VF page on Community is able to see all the links and are clickable.

When the same page is opened by a community user is not able to click the links and the CSS appears to be disrupted. This was working properly till new Spring 20 release. We went through release docs but we cant see any issue causing update.

Minimal Visualforce code:

```
<apex:page> 
    <a href="{!$Site.Prefix}/apex/TestPage" data-content="Test"> 
        <span class="title">Test</span> 
    </a> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Could you please try this issue with a minimal VF page code, in case it still doesn't work; share it with us so that we can replicate the behavior?

Comment: @Raul Yes i tried with a single href and it is not clickable.

Comment: below is the sample code which didnt work on community: <apex:page>
    <a href="{!$Site.Prefix}/apex/TestPage" data-content="Test">     
        <span class="title">Test</span>
    </a>
</apex:page>

Comment: I see thanks, the community type is visualforce + tabs?

Comment: @raul Yes Community type is vf + tabs

Comment: I tried to add the page you mentioned as inline to Account and I see a link in classic [Account detail page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcw9s.png) and same link is also visible on [VF + tabs community](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDXHd.png), links are clickable on both side, so not sure what is wrong at your end. How is the page being displayed on communities?